# Assume that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on [a,b] which of the following statements is not true?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$.

1) Let $f([a,b])=\{f(x)|x\in[a,b]\}$. $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ if and only if $f([a,b])=[f(a),f(b)]$.

2) $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$

I think both of them are true however I'm stuck with showing what I think.

For the first one I know that strictly increasing functions have to be continuous except at most countably many points on any finite interval.

If a strictly increasing function  $f$  is not continuous at $x=a$ then it has to have a jump there. The supremum of the values of  $f$  for $x<a$  has to be greater than the infimum of the values of $f$ for $x>a$.  The jump at  $a$  is the difference between those two values.

Since strictly increasing functions can only be discontinuous at countable many points, therefore they are continuous almost everywhere.

Am I right?

I would be glad if you give me a hint for the second one If my explanation for the first one is correct.

Comment: 2) can't be true in general even if $f$ was differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

For 1) : you can prove it using intermediate value theorem if $f$ is continuous. But what if $f$ is not ? Find a counter-example where $f$ is not continuous.

For 2) : what can you say for $f(x) = x^3$ on $[-1,1]$ ?

Comment: For 1) I think f being continuous implies $f([a,b])=[f(a),f(b)]$ but $f([a,b])=[f(a),f(b)]$ doesn't imply continuity. Am I right? For 2) I've got the idea $f'(x)$ doesn't necessarily be greater than zero. Thank you.

Comment: 1) not exactly. The thing is that if $f$ is not continuous, there is no reason for $f([a,b])$ to be an interval, even if it's strictly increasing. You can find a counter example just by trying to draw its graph.

Comment: One last question, can I assert that if $f([a,b])=[f(a),f(b)]$ then f is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

1) The answer is true.

$(\implies)$ Assume that $f$ is continuous. Since $f$ is strictly increasing, it is clear that $f([a, b]) \subset [f(a), f(b)]$.
For the reverse inclusion, use intermediate value theorem.

$(\impliedby)$ Assume that $f([a, b]) = [f(a), f(b)]$. Let $c \in [a, b]$ be arbitrary. We show that $f$ is continuous at $c$.
Let  $\epsilon > 0$ be given.

Let $\alpha = \max\{f(a), f(c) - \epsilon/3\}$ and $\beta = \min\{f(b), f(c) + \epsilon/3\}$.
Thus, we have that $\alpha, \beta \in [f(a), f(b)]$.

By assumption, $[f(a), f(b)] = f([a, b])$ and thus, there exist (unique) $c_1, c_2 \in [a, b]$ such that $f(c_1) = \alpha$ and $f(c_2) = \beta$.

Note that $c \in [c_1, c_2]$ with $c_1 < c_2$. Thus, we can choose $\delta > 0$ such that

$$|x - c| < \delta \implies x \in [c_1, c_2].$$

Now, for any such $x$, we will have $f(c_1) = \alpha \le f(x) \le \beta = f(c_2)$. (Since $f$ is increasing.)
Also, note that $\alpha \le f(c) \le \beta.$

As $\beta - \alpha \le 2\epsilon/3 < \epsilon,$ we have that

$$|x - c| < \delta \implies x \in [c_1, c_2] \implies |f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$$

and thus, $f$ is continuous at $c$, as desired.

---

2) This is false.
Firstly, it is not implied that $f$ is even continuous, let alone differentiable.
However, even if we assume that $f$ is differentiable, the result is not true. As a counterexample, you may consider the function $x \mapsto x^3$ on $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: @mzg147: hi, your function is not increasing, let alone strictly. $f(0.5) > f(1.25)$ in your case.